# What are the best old electrical appliances to extract electronic components from?

Tags: power-electronics, reference-materials

I would like to build some simple drones and robots which I will be controlling using a microcontroller. Instead of buying expensive brand new components, I prefer to look for old electrical appliances at home or on the internet, and then extract what I need myself (small electrical motors, capacitors, resistors...)

I am really new in this field (I did some basics at university) but never did anything myself. I would like to ask the experts if they have any suggestions as to what are the best cheap appliances from which I can extract some parts easily and will cost only a few euros (or dollars)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you get this idea from watching/reading fiction about some fictional character building robots out of old junk, and therefore you assume it makes sense to do so?

Comment: I saw Iron Man do this in the first film - he was captured and he built himself a rather sophisticated and semi automatic suit. He made it from old tins, bits chipped off rocks, spent human hair and dust. Amazing.

Comment: tl;dr unsolder anything that looks *uncommon* or *strange* to you. Not only you'll develop your ironing skill - you'll learn how to identify electronic parts in no time. FWIW, those common-looking parts are usually those you can buy wholesale in 100s for 1$; those rare-ish ones are usually couple of orders of magnitude harder to get or more pricey. Also, try to locate complete & working *modules* - you can, e.g., remove an entire audio amplifier or EQ from an old cassette player, or you can remove the IR Tx/Rx pair from TV/remote, and refit it to your application.

Comment: You asked about which **expensive** components could be salvaged. Many of the components people are answering below are worth no more than a dollar. *And* they will be old and worn and the desoldering process is certainly not worth the time and effort. New components are more efficient and so damn cheap.

Comment: The book [*Unscrewed*](https://www.amazon.com/Unscrewed-Salvage-Motors-Switches-Electronics/dp/1569766045/) by Ed Sobey details the art of disassembling and reusing parts from household electronics.

Comment: @Lundin no i did not! vaxquis already stated some good reasons out of many

Comment: The fan motors in the example you cite are OK but marginal. Trying various fans may produce a good result. Rewinding CD ROM motors is a very well covered area and it's worth looking at related pages. [**This web search**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?num=100&site=&source=hp&q=rewind+cd+rom+motor&oq=rewind+cd+mo&gs_l=hp.1.0.0i22i30k1.3075.11031.0.14366.19.18.1.0.0.0.412.3991.2-12j1j1.14.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..4.12.2963.0..0j35i39k1j0i131k1j0i10k1j33i21k1.Xr84lkz55cI) gives you lots to look at ...

Comment: ... and the related [**image search**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=rewind+cd+rom+motor&num=100&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMjea6nLLQAhXLK48KHbaTB60QsAQIIA&biw=1120&bih=613) possibly more so.  | These motors are usually rewound to get higher kV ratings (RPM per volt) and more power and people often also improve the magnets. I have not tried it (YET) but just maybe use of higher voltage with unmodified motors may be good enough - cooling is possibly the main limitation. A boost converter to a higher voltage my be acceptably compact and light....

Comment: ...  A switched capacitor converter at constant step up ratio and very high frequency may be practical here.

Comment: @Bort deep-ending where the OP lives and how much discretionary funds he has available the terms he use MAY mean "new components, which are expensive". Possibly not  - but cerain reasonably possible.

Answer (score 9):

Most electronic devices have a range of components. The following are mainly those that are somewhat more special or useful.

Many parts for Robots will be easily  sourced from surplus material.
Drone motors usually need high power per volume and high power per mass and often existing motors will not be adequate. Rewinding of some motors may be possible.

Printers are often a source of small electric motors. Also possibly solenoids, drive belts, mechanical and electromechanical parts & position sensors. Some have mains to low voltage power supplies fitted internally.

Dead (or alive) CFL lightbulbs provide high voltage (mains rated) transistors

LED light bulbs have AC to lower voltage DC conversion circuits but the end voltages may still be quite high.

Some but not all toasters can have timers, solenoids (to release the mechanism if power is removed).

Many consumer main powered portable device provide housings for construction and mains input to low voltage DC power supplies **BUT** be very careful that supplies are mains isolated on the low voltage side - many many not be.

PC/computer power supplied have high voltage transistors and capacitors and noise filter magnetics and mains rated non-polarised capacitors.

Microwave ovens have magnets, turntable motor, interlock switches and the main transformer which is useful but somewhat unusual in its magnetic design - designed to have a saggy output under load. Be aware that the magnetron MAY use fatally dangerous Beryllium ceramic insulator due to its high thermal conductivity.

Be aware that SOME older transformers and high voltage non polarised capacitors MAY use carcinogenic PCB oil for internal insulation and thermal transfer. Not so common.

Televisions contain just about everything :-) - except maybe motors.

TVs, radios and much else are good sources of surface mount components. Learn how to desolder them well. A fine tip iron is usually **NOT** what is needed.

Direct drive washing machines may use high power brushless DC motors useful as seriously powerful motors or for wind or water turbines.

CD & DVD players contain motors which MAY be able to be rewound to have far greater power than originally.

Many more ...

Comment: Dead CFLs are one of the worst component sources, since the circuitry tends to fail in a way that leaves everything shot :)

Comment: LED bulbs are available (with taxpayer subsidies) in my area for about US$0.75 each (60W equivalent). Many of them probably have similar transistors.

Answer (score 9):

The tool you are looking for is most likey a solder iron...

That being said, why would you want to re-use old passive components for? Brand new passive components are ridiculously cheap and more environment-friendly than old ones. In addition, many components age, most notably aluminium electrolyte caps. To salvage those from old electronics would be a bad idea.

Also, old PCBs might be covered in various nasty chemicals like flame retardents and pcb lacquer. These chemicals will pollute the soldering and are hazardous to breathe when you unsolder the components. Preferably, components on such PCBs should be removed while sitting at a fume cupboard.

Why don't you go look around and see what these parts actually cost brand new, first of all? You'll find that your idea of salvaging probably makes little sense in most cases.

Comment: PCB lacquer has nothing to do with "PCB" as a pollutant.

Comment: And btw, the quickest tool is a 2000W thermostat-controlled heat gun. Blow everything off an SMD board, sort out later (tried components salvaged that way, they usually work).

Comment: @rackandboneman No, PCB means Printed Circuit Board... I thought that goes without saying on this site. The fume that comes from [PCB lacquer](https://www.jaycar.us/medias/sys_master/images/h45/hcc/8886990012446/NA1002ImageMain-515Wx515H.jpg) is quite nasty to breathe in, irritates your nose and throat. Most likely not healthy at all. Based on personal experience from doing repairs on PCBs covered with lacquer, I would not recommend it without a fume cupboard.

Comment: So you mean conformal coating, rather than soldermask.

Comment: How could a brand new passive component possibly be more environment-friendly than an old one? The old one has already been produced, not using it will result in it being thrown away; whereas buying a new one will (at least indirectly) result in a new one being produced. Surely not producing a new component and using an existing one is the more environment-friendly choice.

Comment: @GlenYates Because if you recycle the old component, the lead, cadmium, polybrominated phenyls and other very harmful and dangerous substances can be removed from the market in a controlled manner, so that humans and the environment won't be exposed to them any longer. If you put it back to use, it will end up anywhere, where it can once again be harmful. Besides, "I'll re-use this old, highly cancerous stuff to save the environment" doesn't really sound like common sense to me.

Comment: @Lundin fyi only - The term PCB is more ambiguous in this context than you may realise. PCB also can mean [**Polychlorinated bi phenyl**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychlorinated_biphenyl) and PCB based substances were once commonly used for cooling and dielectic enhancement in some transformers, some capacitors and other unexpected uses such as some "carbon-free 'carbon paper'". They are considered a persistent organic pollutant with a range of known and/or postulated dangers. PCB lacquer may (perhaps) exist on some old equipment - if so one does not want to deal with it.

Answer (score 6):

In the days when electronics hobbyists build radios using 5 transistors and a linear power supply using 10 transistors (a fancy one :-) ) then indeed it would be possible to re-use some components found in discarded radios and televisions.

But fast forward to the 21st century and a lot has changed. Most consumer products use a few ICs which are often proprietary and only suitable for that application. In a TV you'll find a TV-chip. There will be some discrete components but this will often be SMD components, not handy for a beginner. And only of you can identify the component. And I can buy 20 brand new ones on Ebay for $1 and then I know the type so I can look at the datasheet.

You want to build (simple) drones and robots. Do you have any idea what the complexity is needed to make a drown fly, OK not much but you might want to be able to remotely control it ? Then you need a radio chip and not the one that is in a TV. They both might contain 10,000 transistors (just a guess) the TV chip and a drone's radio chip I mean. My point is that the complexity of drones etc is such that you will not find much useful components in everyday electronics.

Also, components and kits to build something yourself is now so cheap that there is little point in trying to re-use discarded components. I often use an Arduino clone from Ebay for my projects, these cost less than $ 2 each. Sure there are microcontrollers in consumer devices as well but for me these are not as easy to use as an Arduino.

Comment: And the brushless motors and the ESC that would be required for a drone will be nowhere near any old electronics or electrical items -unrelated to hobby - at home

Comment: "not handy for a beginner", but keep these boards around, some of the stuff is useful to the advanced hobbyist.

Comment: @HankyPanky FYI: Rewound DVD / CD ROM drive motors are extensively used by a niche but large segment of the RC modelling community. Small and very useful indeed motors can be made this way - acceptable power to weight ratios compared to commercial alternatives and well above tgeminmum power levels needed for eg "quad copters".

Answer (score 3):

When I was a kid, I used to disassemble the old electronic devices my parents were getting rid of so I could build circuits that I found in electronics magazines.  One of the best sources for components was old VCRs.  They have great motors in them, and a wide variety of resistors, capacitors, and transistors.  You just need a decent soldering iron, a steady hand, and possibly a desoldering tool.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of appliances have reusable 8051-type microcontrollers - they are ubiquitous in monitors, TVs, white goods, car electronics, early harddrives and CDROM drives... and if you combine them with an external program memory (28F... series flash chips or 27C... series EPROMs are often suitable, and can be found in a lot of older computer scrap) and a means to write to it (specialized kit - build it or ebay it), they are an old-school but fun MCU platform. Almost all of the 40/68/84-Pin versions can be wired up in a way to use an external program memory, even if they are ROM or OTP devices.

Optical mice very often have an 68HCxx based reprogrammable MCU in them.

Also, always look for professional-grade, military, industrial control, or test equipment - these tend to use valuable, well documented generic ICs rather than application-specific parts.

Also, text-only, one to four line, monochrome alphanumeric LCD displays found in all kinds of equipment are often of the well-documented HD44780-like type. Forget about any LCD displays that work with custom segments (not very useful and difficult to drive), except such that are made to work with a voltmeter chip like ICL7106 usually found in the same equipment.

Comment: A brand new Cortex M0 costs around 1€. Why would you go dig for old crap MCUs from the Jurassic period? I'd gladly pay hundred times more if it meant that I didn't have to work with some icky old relic like 8051, 68HCxx or PIC. And how are you gonna program them? You'd have to go dig for tools too. Program an 8051 in assembler then build your own in-circuit debugger based on some questionable hobbyist schematics found on the internet? No thanks. I'd rather be up and running on an ARM, with a free C compiler in less than 1 hour.

Comment: 8051 is elegant, and it doesn't seem to really die, so you can concentrate on programming rather than having to learn a new MCU every few years :)

Comment: @rackandboneman: If you use a modern chip targeted by GCC or LLVM, you'll never have to learn any MCU. Just write high-level code.

Comment: @rackandboneman Why would you call one of the least code-efficient CPUs ever made elegant? Elegant like an elephant in the porcelain store. Time to pick up C programming, perhaps.

Comment: Compared to a PIC with its mix up of registers and RAM, I find the 8051 model very elegant :) And I was talking C.

Answer (score 2):

When I was in junior high (often called middle school now), I got a hold of a pinball machine that had been seized at a local men's club because members were using it for gambling.  Now most kids would want to keep the machine as is in their bedroom and play all day, like today's video games.  Not me, I was more interested in the innards.

So I tore it all down and the parts inside (all electromechanical, this was 55+ years ago -- relays, switches, motors, etc.) provided me a wealth of parts that I used for projects for many years thereafter.

The technology has obviously changed a lot since then, but I would assume a newer pinball machine (I mean a real one, with flippers and lights etc, not a CRT or LCD) would still have lots of interesting electromechanical stuff inside, especially for robotics, along with a PCB with a microcontroller that may or may not be usable, but it would at least have some driver circuitry.